# how to link backend custom fields of product to product specification tab in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Under the "Product Specification" tab, i want to  link this to the "Custom Fields" on the back-end(by "Back-end" I mean the control panel where you login and can modify the product) of the website. If you go to each product on the back-end, each product has a "Custom Field" tab that has the product specifications set up. I want the "Custom Field" contents in the back-end for each product to show under the "Product Specification" tab of the product's page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're developing on Stencil or Blueprint, so I will explain both.

**Stencil**

In Stencil, first navigate to the templates/components/products/product-view.html file. Locate the custom fields code, and move it to the Product Details tab. Using handlebars, we will add the class name to the custom-field `<li>` and render the fields. If you only have one field, you may want to use a `<p>` tag instead of `<li>`.

```
{{#if product.custom_fields}}
    <ul>
    {{#each product.custom_fields}}
        <li class="custom-field {{name}}"><span>{{name}}:</span> {{{value}}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/if}}
```

**Blueprint**

The Custom Fields Snippet, is located inside the ProductOtherDetails.html Panel. Inside this Panel, it calls the %%SNIPPET_ProductCustomFields%% which loops each custom field. Code below.

```
<div class="DetailRow %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%">
    <div class="Label">%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%:</div>
    <div class="Value">
        %%GLOBAL_CustomFieldValue%%
    </div>
</div>
```

I recommend adding the `%%GLOBAL_CustomFieldName%%` as a class on the DetailRow as a way to target each custom field using JS/CSS if you have more than one.

If you have more than one custom field and you only want to move the one field to the product description, I recommend using Javascript. Something like:

```
$('.DetailRow.CUSTOMFIELDNAME').detach().appendTo('.ProductDescription');
```

If you only have one custom field or you'd like all your custom fields in the product description, you can just move the Panel to the ProductDesription Panel which will render those custom fields in the product description.

Hope this helps.